# How to reduce repetitive javascript code

Tags: javascript, repeat

Is there anyway I can reduce the repetition below? I have only shown two code blocks but there are and will be many more of the same.

I have tried using arrays and loops, but unfortunately I could not get a working example. Thank you in advance.

```
E1 = new Audio('audio/E1.ogg');
E1.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  this.currentTime = 0;
  this.play();
}, false);

A1 = new Audio('audio/A1.ogg');
A1.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  this.currentTime = 0;
  this.play();
}, false);
```

**EDIT :** Using Jonathan's code below, I am still wondering whether it would be possible to do the equivalent of:

```
(E1,A1,x,x,x).addEventListener('ended', callback, false);
// I know this bit of code doesn't work
```

Comment: You should leave the original code you had in the question.  As it is, the accepted answer is confusing because it looks like exactly what you already had in the question.

Comment: @davy8: I am not sure why I never saw this comment, but it definitely makes sense. I have rolled the question back and re-edited so that future answer seekers will be able to easily see what the solution was solving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your callbacks are the same you can just bind them to a variable:

```
var E1 = new Audio('audio/E1.ogg');
var A1 = new Audio('audio/A1.ogg');

var callback = function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
};

E1.addEventListener('ended', callback, false);
A1.addEventListener('ended', callback, false);
```

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't spot creating a callback variable. I think I must have gotten code blindness from staring at all the other code!

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
var addEndedEvent = function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);
}

addEndedEvent(new Audio('audio/A1.ogg'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var files = ['audio/E1.ogg', 'audio/A1.ogg'];
//note that we cannot/should not use for(... in ...) - that won't do what you expect
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
    var audio = new Audio(files[i]);
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this. If you have more files, just add their name into the array `fileNames`.

```
var audioRefs = { }, fileNames = ['E1','A1','B1'], i, file;
for( i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++ ) {
    file = fileNames[i];
    audioRefs[file] = new Audio('audio/' + file + '.ogg');
    audioRefs[file].addEventListener('ended', callback, false);
}

function callback() {
   this.currentTime = 0;
   this.play();
};
```

`audioRefs` will end up looking like....

```
audioRefs = {
   'A1': (reference to A1 Audio object),
   'B1': (reference to B1 Audio Object)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the edited question, if you use the `each` function from [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each) you can do the following:

```
_.each([E1,A1,B1], function(audio) { 
    audio.addEventListener('ended', callback, false); 
});
```